# Reconnecting WCF clients after a service receive timeout has occured

Tags: wpf, wcf, communication

I have a WCF service which I host inside a WFP application, which acts as one of the clients of service as well. There is one more WPF app which acts as another client for service. After a timeout occurs and clients get disconnected, What is the proper way to clean up resources and connect the clients again. I am trying to create new proxies but I am not able to use them for communication. I know I can increase the recieve timeout on service but I need my clients to be able to communicate always not just for long enough. I have also tried continously sending a message to service at interval but that's something I don't want to go for. What approach is best for continous communication between clients and service? My service might need to be connected to clients for months or may be years.

Any help will be of great value.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you keep up the connection to the service the whole time? It's a security leak and the session on the server side get unnecessarily bigger.

Comment: Kroax, I am using WCF service for two WPF apps to be able to communicate with each other, and these apps are long running, keep running for months or may be years as I said. That's why I need clients to be connected. I am not ver familiar with WCF services. Should I be using some other approach for my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the CommunicationException or something like that and then restore the channel.